# Woocommerce Review Tab visible only for customers who bought the product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display the Woocommerce "Review" tab only for "verified owners" (customers who actually bought that product)

A user that didn't buy that product will not be able to even see the review tab.

i found this code - the thing is that instead of "if(empty($comments))" should be something that knows to check if the user bought that product or not.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

global $product;
$id = $product->id;

$args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
$comments = get_comments( $args );

if(empty($comments)) {
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
}

return $tabs;
}
```

i also found this code that might help solving this:

```
global $product;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id)) {
```

can anyone help me connecting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the condition returns true if user has bought that product so we can unset it in else part.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

global $product;
$id = $product->id;

 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id));
// do nothing
else
unset( $tabs['reviews'] );

return $tabs;
}
```